# \textheight varies slightly

Tags: textheight

My tags are:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{12}{15}%
   \abovedisplayskip 12\p@ %\@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@%
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ %\@plus3\p@%
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ %\@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@%
   \belowdisplayskip 12\p@ %\@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@%
   \let\@listi\@listI}%
\normalsize%
\makeatother

1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10\\
1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\20\\
1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\30\\
1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\40\\

\end{document}
```

If you see the output in `PDF` with `Grid`, then you can realize that very minor variation in each line, that is first few lines slightly down with Grid, after that (exactly from line number 18), it was base aligned with Grid, how can I align all lines in a same position? Please suggest...

[image]

Note, I've created the Grid line in `AdobeAcrobat Professional` with the following setup:

[image]

Comment: your lines are equally spaced, are you sure it isn't just your grid lines are not aligned with the baselines?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry if my understanding is not correct, if the lines are equally spread, then the Grid and the text base should align, hope I'm correct.... Please advise...

Comment: you have given no indication of how you drew the grid lines, so I can't say anything

Comment: Sorry, Grid line created in `AdobeAcrobat Professional", will update in my post

Comment: so the grid lines are 15bp apart and your text baselines are 15pt apart so will get gradually further apart as you move down the page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It meant that nothing wrong with the output, am I correct?

Comment: as far as I can see, nothing is wrong other than you haven't set the grid to match your text

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sir, much thanks for your valuable time spent to clarify my doubt...Shall I remove this post?

Comment: try setting your acrobat grid spacing to 14.944pt instead of 15pt

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No words to say....It's wonderful and amazing... it solves my problem accurately.... Much thanks .....Can you make this as answer? so that I'll accept it and it will help in future to some body....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid line specification is using PostScript Points (1in/72) not TeX Points (1in/72.27) so to have acrobat show grid lines matching the TeX baselineskip you want to specify a distance of

15 * 72 / 72.27 ~ 14.944 pt